# is it possible to get the path id that surrounds the text after the text was clicked, without grouping

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

Im creating an inddor map, I have an svg and im not sure if its possible to get the path id (store1) when i clicked the text (TENANT A) and path id (store2) when i clicked the text (TENANT B)

here is my svg:

```html
 <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5749.8 2421.9">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;}
        .st6{fill:#FBB040;stroke:#000000;}
        .st7{fill:#238DDE;stroke:#000000;}
        .st8{font-family:'ArialMT';}
    </style>
        <g id="tenant">
            <path id="store1" class="st3" d="M909.5,486.8l137.5,0.1h89.7V5.5H871.4v442.9l7.3,4.3l6.7,4.8
                l6.1,5.2l5.3,5.5l5,5.9l3.5,4.5l2.3,3.3l1.3,2.3l0.6,1.5l0.1,0.9L909.5,486.8z"/>
                
                 <path id="store2" class="st3" d="M563.5,5.5v445.2h36v36.6h142l8.3-12.3l9.9-10.5l11-8.7l11.6-7
   l11.7-5.4l11.3-3.8l10.5-2.2l9.1-0.7l6.3,0.2l6.2,0.6l6.1,1l5.9,1.3l5.8,1.7l5.6,2l5.4,2.3l5.2,2.5V5.5H563.5z"/>
        </g> 
        <g id="label"> 
            <text transform="matrix(4 0 0 4 907.5792 196.5629)" class="st8 st9">TENANT A</text>
            
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 647.8267 193.2297)" class="st8 st9">TENANT B</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I tried adding event listener to the text but i cant even get the right path id when clicking the text
Any suggestions or idea would help, i know snap.svg as a tool for playing around svg but the answer seems not in there also, thanks

Comment: It's likely possible...but you have to explain what the link is in terms of tenant-a to store-1, as there isn't any particular link in the dom ? Is it just that they are the 1st elements in the tenant and label groups..and for the next one, it's the 2nd element in both the tenant and label group, or is there something else ?

Comment: Hi @Ian, what link are you reffering to? this is an actual format of the svg, the text tags was inside label group and there is no actual format for text, all text tags was scattered around label group.

Comment: the paths and text elements can be multiplied like there will be store 3 --> TENANT C, the store locations will be multiplied in the future

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you could rearrange the svg so that the matching label/tenant are in a group element not sure if that's possible ? Otherwise it would be possible, but I think you would need to loop through the group, find which relative element that is in the array, and then find the matching one in the other array, which feels like a lot harder work that in should be. Or could you given them similar names like el1store and el1label, el2store and el2label etc ? Rather than the names being completely different ? Again, it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is the wrong way around I just realised, but you could still do it like this, but swap C -> 3, b -> 2 etc if there is a literal naming convention. This is the bit that's not clear...

original:

Well, it's not clear how tenant is related to label. If it's just tenant1 is always the first element in labels or what. You haven't described the logic of the structure of the svg, in terms of 'why' tenantc = store3 (position or alphabet or whatever...)

I've done an example which will get you part there, this is based on the point that I'm assuming Tenant B is in the 2nd store..

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9f0pt5/

```
var s = Snap("svg");

var tenants = s.select("#tenant");
var labels  = s.select("#label");
var regex = /store(.*)/;

tenants.click( function( el ){
  var store = el.target.id.match(regex)[1];
  var tenant =  labels.selectAll("text")[store-1];
  alert(store + ', ' + tenant.attr('text'));
});
```

Just realised this was the wrong way around, you could still do this and convert C=>3, b=>2 etc...